# How can I have Messages show chat history from other devices?

Tags: macos, messages, google-hangouts

I have Google Hangouts enabled on my Messages application. I can send and receive Hangouts messages fine, but if I pickup the conversation on my phone for a while and then return back to my computer, I have no chat history from the time I was on my phone.

Is there a way to have Messages pull in chat history from other devices? The Hangouts app on my phone pulls in chat history just fine from the Messages app on my Mac, so I don't see why it shouldn't work just as easy the other way around.

Comment: I'm not a big user of this service, but have you tried this in the Messages app: Preferences > Accounts > [your Gmail account] > Chat Settings > In chat rooms, show, and then select, say *The last 200 messages*?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't see `Chat Settings` in my version of messenger though.

Comment: By "Messenger", do you mean the "Messages" app?

Comment: Yes, I'll update the title.